# android - a clicked item in RecyclerView on some devices becomes invisible after returning on current activity

Tags: android, click, android-recyclerview, onbackpressed

I encountered a strange problem. I have a **RecyclerView** and when I click on its item opens new **Activity**. On my phone everything's okay - clicked, opened, pressed Back button, everything as it was before. But *on some devices* a clicked item *is lost* after returning (looks like it was replaced with something transparent and unclickable with the same size). Other items are okay.

Anyone encountered the same issue? What reasons can be? Help me please!

Comment: Can you post your `Adaptor` code and `onClickListener` for the item?